# OS X Lion, ImageMagick and RMagic - how to install?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, osx-lion, homebrew, rmagick

I am trying to install ImageMagick and RMagic, because they don't work after the OS X Lion upgrade.
When I ran

```
brew install imagemagick
```

I got the error

```
Error: You must `brew link libpng' before imagemagick can be installed
```

But when I run `brew link libpng` as is mentioned in the error message, I'll get:

```
Error: You must `brew link libpng' before imagemagick can be installed
Radek-Macs-MacBook-Pro-3:sharelock-staging radek$ brew link libpng
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/libpng/1.5.13... Warning: Could not link libpng. Unlinking...

Error: Could not symlink file: /usr/local/Cellar/libpng/1.5.13/include/pnglibconf.h
/usr/local/include/pnglibconf.h may already exist.
/usr/local/include may not be writable.
```

How to fix this issue? I am solving the RMagic thing two days without any success... this is a pure nightmare...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had this complaint from `brew` before. It was solved in my case by unlinking, then relinking; that is, running `brew unlink "libname"`, then `brew link "libname"`, substituting for "libname" the name of the software that isn't linking right; in your case, "libpng".

Comment: If I will run the `brew unlink libname`, I'll get `Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/libname`. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: sorry, I guess that wasn't clear. substitute "libname" with the name of the library you're having trouble linking, in your case libpng. My trouble wasn't with libpng, it was a different library, but it was the same error message, and it might be solved the same way. I'll update my answer to clarify.

Comment: Thanks for your message Mark. Please, see the OP, when I try to `link` the library, I get the error mentioned in the OP. When I run `brew unlink libpng`, then I get the message `Linking /usr/local/Cellar/libpng/1.5.13... Warning: Could not link libpng. Unlinking...`... what could I try now?

Comment: did you run the **`unlink`**  command? because the error message you are showing should only ever be given by the **`link`** command.

Comment: The idea being that sometimes there are bad links for a library, and you need to remove them before you can link it properly; therefore: `unlink`, then `link`

Answer (score 6):

Ran into the same problem for me I ran:

```
$ brew unlink jpeg 
$ brew link --overwrite jpeg
$ brew unlink libpng
$ brew link --overwrite libpng 
$ brew install imagemagick
```

and pow I got imagemagick up and running

Answer (score 3):

This just happened to me in Mountain Lion when trying to install libpng with brew.

```
sudo chown <user>:wheel /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/
```

Fixed this for me.

Answer (score 0):

Check the file permissions on the `/usr/local/include` directory:

`$ ls -ld /usr/local/include`

This should show whether you have the right permissions to create a symbolic link to that directory.  An easy way to check is:

`$ touch /usr/local/include/mydummytestfile && rm /usr/local/include/mydummytestfile`

If the previous command succeeds, then you do have access. On the other hand, if you get the error:

`touch: /usr/local/include/mydummytestfile: Permission denied`, then you will need to run the `brew` command using the `sudo` command as:

`$ sudo brew link libpng`

You will need to provide your password. Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, `touch /usr/local/include/mydummytestfile && rm /usr/local/include/mydummytestfile` succeded, but what now?